# Sum of Javascript array returns 0 first

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sum

Having a massive nightmare, trying to calculate the sum of an array (of numbers), in ReactJS/State.

The code I've posted below works, if I'm not using state.

1. Basically, via a form a user enters a number and then submits.
2. What the user types, is watched via handleChange.
3. And then on handlSubmit, the number/value is stored in this.state.donated and this.state.sum.  These are arrays.

When I look at console, both states, store an array of numbers. And collect each entry into the array fine.

**I want to find and print the total of these numbers.  So I'm using:**

```
// FUNCTION TO CALCULATE TOTAL DONATIONS
const numbers = this.state.sum;
function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
// // TOTAL VALUE OF NUMBERS IN THE ARRAY
const cal = numbers.reduce(add, 0);
console.log('CALC', cal);
```

However, the problem I'm having is, if I submit for example, number 20.  The sum function, console logs **0** first.  When I enter a second number, it then console logs the first number I entered...

What am I doing wrong?  There's my full/relevant code:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
   super();

   this.state = {
     number: '',
     donated: [],
     sum: [],
     total: 0
   };

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
 // we need to bind otherwise this is undefined
 }


//HANDLE FUNCTIONS
 handleChange(e) {
   this.setState({ number: e.target.value }, () => 
   console.log('NUMBER', this.state.number));
 }

 handleSubmit(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({donated: this.state.donated.concat(this.state.number).map(Number)}, () => console.log('DONATED', this.state.donated));
 this.setState({sum: this.state.donated.concat(this.state.number).map(Number)}, () => console.log('SUM', this.state.sum));


 // FUNCTION TO CALCULATE TOTAL DONATIONS
 const numbers = this.state.sum;
  function add(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

// TOTAL VALUE OF NUMBERS IN THE ARRAY
const cal = numbers.reduce(add, 0);
console.log('CALC', cal);


document.forms['id_form'].reset();
}

render() {

return (
  <main>
    <section className="section">
      <h1 className="is-size-2">DONATE FOR A GOOD CAUSE</h1>
      <ProgressBar donated={this.state.donated} sum={this.state.sum}/>
      <Form donated={this.state.donated} handleChange={this.handleChange} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
    </section>
  </main>
);
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Please share complete code

Comment: you can use this template to share your working example https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ERYXYg

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: I can't really do that?  I've used multiple components?  I don't think I can rebuild the entire app using that link.....  I'd have to change my code...

Comment: I have found out your problem, setState is async function it do not change state right after calling it and you are using state right after calling set state which still contains old values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.

Use setState callBack to calculate sum to get updated values

```
this.setState({sum: this.state.donated.concat(this.state.number).map(Number)}, () => {
    console.log('SUM', this.state.sum);
    // FUNCTION TO CALCULATE TOTAL DONATIONS
    const numbers = this.state.sum;
    function add(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    // TOTAL VALUE OF NUMBERS IN THE ARRAY
    const cal = numbers.reduce(add, 0);
    console.log('CALC', cal);


    document.forms['id_form'].reset();
});
```

or you can simply update a sum variable after every new value submission. like this

```
setState({sum: this.state.sum + this.state.number, number: 0});
```

Comment: ok thank you, what's the best way to structure that into my code?

Comment: AMAZING!!!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! Really appreciate your help!  I knew it had something to do with the ordering.  Appreciate the knowledge transfer.  And learned something new today.  Thank you! :D